# apache conf entry does not work but does in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

i am running:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
```

i have a custom security conf file on a shared server.

i placed the following entry at the top of the file with no joy, and i also placed it at the bottom, also with no joy.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(wp-comments-post|wp-login)\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://error.myworkdomain.com/index.html [F,L]
```

but it works in .htaccess.

ideas?

Comment: It is supposed to go into .htaccess, which is the file that mod_rewrite uses to do it's work.

Answer (score 1):

If the mod_rewrite works in a .htaccess then you should be able to put it in   tags with the directory pointing to the dir which you used to put the .htaccess in.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a  you have to add `Options FollowSymLinks` as stated in the [official doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).
That is what you're using if using a .htaccess.
For example  (with /path/to/your/dir where the .htaccess is)

```
<Directory /Path/to/your/dir>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```